# How to generate a PHP QR Code with dynamic text variable

Tags: php, qr-code

I am using PHPQRcode from sourceforge https://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/

I am able to generate static QR code on the webpage using text in double quotes pointing to a url, but I need to link this to a record stored in my database so that the URL is dynamic (the 'id' variable below ) please advise.

```
<?php 
$id=$row["job_number"];

include 'phpqrcode/qrlib.php'; 

$text = "$id"; 

$path = 'images/'; 
$file = $path.uniqid().".png"; 

$ecc = 'L'; 
$pixel_Size = 10; 
$frame_Size = 10; 


QRcode::png($text, $file, $ecc, $pixel_Size, $frame_size); 

echo "<center><img src='".$file."'></center>"; 
?>
```

Comment: If `$row["job_number"]` is the data fetched from the database, this code should work. The QR Code library doesn't care where you got it from.